# Parse a JSON column with a FOR loop for every record?

Tags: json, postgresql, for-loop, plpgsql, set-returning-functions

Being a novice to Postgres and SQL in general, I have the following scenario in Postgres 9.6:

`table1`

```
"Myjson" JSON
"DateOfAcquisition"  DATE
"Id" INT
```

In `"Myjson"` there is a list which I iterate trough with a `FOR` loop.

**My objective** is to place the elements of each json list in `table1` in another table:

`table2`

```
jsonelem1 INT
jsonelem2 INT
"DateOfAcquisition" DATE
"Id" INT
```

I have written the following code for parsing the json field but I am not sure how to run the `for` loop for each record of the first table.

```
    DO
$BODY$
DECLARE
    omgjson json := myjsonfield; -- this should change for every row of the first table
    i json;
    myJsonelem1 INT;
    myJsonelem2 INT;

begin

FOR i IN SELECT * FROM json_array_elements(omgjson)
  loop
    myJsonelem2 i->>  'jsonsubfield'::INT;

    INSERT INTO destinationTable VALUES (myJsonelem2,DateOfAcquisition);
END LOOP;

END;
$BODY$ language plpgsql
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some sample JSON data and the result based on that data.[**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). [Edit] your question do not post code in comments

Comment: Surround the `FOR` loop with an outer `FOR` loop that loops through the table: `FOR var1, var2, ... IN SELECT ... FROM ... LOOP`.

Comment: Thanks Lawrence, that is what I did in the end. I was really wondering if there was a better way to do it.

In the answer the double for loop.

Comment: Your 1st "TABLE2" was supposed to be "TABLE1", i assume, and took the liberty to fix the question accordingly.

Comment: A sample JSON value to test would help this question a lot.

Answer (score 1):

A set-based approach is typically *much* faster (and shorter and less error prone) than looping.

Building on the **setup [of your *answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50573069/939860)**, which is largely different from the one in your question.

```
INSERT INTO table2(myfield, data)  -- cleaner: explicit target columns
SELECT k."myField", j.i ->> 'data'
FROM   table1 k, json_array_elements(k."ScrapedJson" -> 'calendar_days') j(i)
WHERE  NOT k."HasBeenProcessed"
-- ORDER BY ???  -- you might want to order rows favorably?
```

The implicit **`LATERAL`** join is the key technique here.

```
... FROM   table1 k, json_array_elements(...) ...
```

is short for:

```
... FROM   table1 k
    CROSS  JOIN LATERAL json_array_elements(...) ...
```

Obviously, `"ScrapedJson" -> 'calendar_days'` is a JSON array, not a "list" like you wrote in the question.

Related:

- [What is the difference between LATERAL and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)

#### Asides

Do yourself a favor and avoid double-quoted CaMeL-case names in Postgres. A wild mix of quoted and *unquoted* identifiers in your question and answer only serves to confuse. I quoted column names in your question to match your answer somewhat. My standing advise: Use legal, lower-case, unquoted names exclusively.

- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)

Consider the data type `jsonb` instead of `json` for most workloads.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Lawrence here is the solution for anybody interested.

I wonder, is there a better way to this?

```
DO
$BODY$
DECLARE
    i json;
    k RECORD;
    mydata INT;
begin

FOR k IN SELECT * from TABLE1 where "HasBeenProcessed" = FALSE
    LOOP  

            FOR i IN SELECT * FROM json_array_elements(k."ScrapedJson" -> 'calendar_days')
              LOOP

                mydata = i->> 'data';

                INSERT INTO "Table2" VALUES (k."myField",mydata);

            END LOOP;


end LOOP;


END;
$BODY$ language plpgsql
```

Comment: Your answer seems to  build on completely different tables than presented in your question ...